# How to initialize GMSCoorindateBounds with GMSVisibleRegion

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, swift

I saw this code for objective c, but I'm trying to do the same thing in swift...

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
....
GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
GMSCoordinateBounds bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion: visibleRegion];
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Just the third line of code I don't know what to do with in swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it like this...

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
var visibleRegion : GMSVisibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: visibleRegion.nearLeft, coordinate: visibleRegion.farRight)
```